# Doubt on Action of $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action, interactions, propagator

I am reading a [paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2007/105) ([arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1671)) in QFT. I am stuck at this point,

$$S [\phi (x)]={1\over 2}\int\phi (x_1)D (x_1 -x_2)\phi (x_2)dx_1dx_2 $$ $$+{\lambda \over 4!}\int V (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \phi(x_1)\phi (x_2)\phi (x_3) \phi (x_4) dx_1 dx_2dx_3dx_4.\tag{9}$$

Here  $D (x_1-x_2)$ is an inverse propagator.

I have 3 doubts:

1. In LHS $\phi$ is a function of $x$ but in RHS there is no $x$. Why?
2. How the inverse propagator comes?
3. Here we are studying $\phi^4$ theory so, how $V (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ comes in second term of RHS?

Answer (score 2):

1. $S[\phi(x)]$ is a common misleading notation often used in physics. The symbol $x$ is here a half-baked attempt to indicate that the function $\phi$ is a function of $x$. The author is *not* saying that the action $S$ only depends on the value $\phi(x)$ at the point $x\in\mathbb{R}^4$. In fact the action functional $S[\phi]$ depends on the function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}$. A better notation is perhaps $S[x\!\mapsto\!\phi(x)]$.
2. The fact that the quadratic action term is the inverse propagator is e.g. explained in Refs. 1-2; [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367763/2451) duplicate Phys.SE question; or in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/270456/2451).
3. The author writes down the most general (possibly non-local) quartic interaction term.

References:

1. L.H. Ryder, *QFT,* 2nd eds., 1996; eq. (6.13).
2. L.S. Brown, *QFT,* 1992; eq. (3.2.10).

Comment: I don't get answer for my second  question from your link, Can you explain it a little more bit @Qmechanic

Comment: I updated the answer.