# Interpretation of $\phi^n$ terms in Lagrangian density

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, perturbation-theory, interactions

Why in QFT are $\phi^n$, where $n>2 $, terms in your lagrangian density interpreted as interaction terms?

so $\phi^4$ is considered a self-interaction term.

Similarly for two different fields $\phi,\chi$ one would say $\phi^2 \chi^2$ is interpreted as the interaction between the two fields.

But I do not understand why they are interpreted as such.

Comment: Do you know the associated Feynman rules?

Answer (score 1):

- Let us introduce the notation that $S_n$ denotes action terms that depend on the $n$th power of the fields.
- A quadratic action $S_2$ (and hence linear EL equations) corresponds to a free (=non-interacting) theory.
- The quadratic part $S_2$ is related to the propagators, or equivalently, the lines in Feynman diagrams, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/649644/2451).
- $S_{\geq 3}$ is the interaction part. The Feynman rule for $S_n$ with $n\geq3$ is an $n$-vertex. In this way $n$ fields interact, cf. OP's title question.
- For more details, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/270428/2451) Phys.SE post.