# Propagator Terms for Different Types of Particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions, propagator

It is possible in the correct gauge to write the first term of the Yang-Mills Lagrangian as $$\text{tr} ( -\frac{1}{2} \partial^{\mu} A^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}),$$ where $A_{\mu}$ is a traceless hermitian $N \times N$ matrix.  This term can then be used in QCD to derive the gluon propagator.

Is there a reason why the propagator is derived from the term with two derivatives, whereas in QED the propagator is derived by considering what is between $\psi$ and $\overline{\psi}$ in the term below, where is only one derivative?

$$\overline{\psi} ( i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} - m ) \psi.$$

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367763/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free propagator is derived from the kinetic term of your lagrangian. For the case of the Dirac equation the kinetic term is:

$\bar{\psi}(i\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu - m)\psi$

In Yang Mills theories, this operator is the trace of the G-connection curvature:

$C Tr( F^2)$

With $C$ a constant you have to impose, usually $C = \frac{-1}{2}$. $F^2$ is to be understood as:

$F^2 = F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$

And

$F_{\mu\nu} = T^a F_{\mu\nu}^a$

This operator in the "right" gauge becomes the one you said.

Comment: For example, if one has a term which is some other combination of a derivative with a pair of fields which differs from the kinetic term which one would expect, is that term physically meaningless?

Comment: No, it's not meaningless, but usually if the fields are of the same type, it's a kinetic term. If it's of 2 different types it could be a yukawa coupling, like the terms giving mass to the SM fermions. I have never seen a term like $\psi\partial_{\mu}\phi$ to be honest

Comment: But for example if you had a doublet like the Higgs doublet $\phi$ and then made a term like $\phi^{\dagger}i \partial_{\mu} \phi$ where the $\mu$ index is contracted with another tensor, this is not the kinetic term for a scalar so what would the term correspond to?

Comment: It depends on the tensor. If the tensor describes another field, it is an interaction, particularly a derivative interaction. Derivative interactions modify the canonical commutation relations