# How do we interpret the second-order differential operator in the QFT path integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

For the free scalar field theory, the path integral has a differential operator term in the exponent,

$$
Z[J] = \int \mathcal{D}\phi \, \exp\left( i \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \int d^d x \, \phi(x) A \phi(x) + \int d^d x \, J(x) \phi(x) \right] \right).
$$

When we solve the integral, we get the inverse ${A}^{-1}$ of the second-order differential operator ${A}$. This is interpreted as the quantum propagator, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367763/2451) Phys.SE post. My question is, if this is interpreted as the quantum propagator, should we interpret the differential operator as the differential operator of the *quantum* Klein-Gordon equation for a free scalar particle? Instead of the usual interpretation as the differential operator of the *classical* Klein-Gordon field.

Comment: How you "interpret" $A$ is rather up to you. It *is* just the usual KG differential opertor $-\nabla^2+m^2$   acting on functions in ${\mathbb R}^4$.

Comment: So am I allowed to interpret it as the differential operator of the quantum Klein-Gordon equation? If so, that would make the term “second quantisation” actually valid.