Is there any intuitive reason why 2-point functions are inverse operators to the free Lagrangian?
To compute $n$-point functions in quantum field theory we use Wick's theorem to reduce this problem to computing 2-point functions. In many textbooks, such as Peskin & Schroeder, the 2-point functions are computed directly and as a consequence it is shown that the solution ends up being a Green's function for the free theory. For example, this is how they introduce the Klein-Gordon propagator.
Another way to phrase this is that the 2-point function is the inverse operator to the free theory, i.e. if the free theory is given by a differential operator $L$ then the 2-point function is equivalent to a function (or distribution) $f$ such that
$$Lf = \delta.$$
I have a feeling that there is something deeper going on here but I have been unable to find anything useful in any textbooks. Is there any intuitive reason why 2-point functions are inverse operators to the free Lagrangian? In other words, what allows/motives us to compute the 2-point function by simply "inverting the operator"?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367763/2451

@Qmechanic I took a look at that post and I think it is slightly different than mine. The answers there explain how the propagator is the Green's function to the equations of motion. However what I am asking in this question is why we are interested in finding the Green's function in the first place. Why do we care about Green's functions when computing 2-point functions?

The relation between the 2-pt function and the Greens function is also discussed in that thread.

@Qmechanic The answers all say that the propagator must be the inverse of the kinetic and mass terms or show their equivalence. However I don't see any of them discussing why the 2-point function is a Green's function without calculating them. Is there a physical reason why expect them to be the same?

OP's new question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808767/2451
