Why are 2-point functions Green's functions?
I asked a question about this earlier but I think it was unfocused so I have rephrased it and asked it again.
The propagator/two-point function $\langle \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\rangle$ for any theory can be found by finding the Green's function $G$ to the free theory, see e.g. this Phys.SE post. That is, if $L$ denotes the differential operator of the free theory then we would like to find $G$ such that $LG = \delta$.
I would like to know why the above is true. To be clear, I understand that one can directly compute the 2-point function and substitute the answer in the equations of motion to verify that it is indeed a Green's function. However, why do we expect this to be true? In other words, is there any reason why the 2-point function should be a Green's function to the free theory? Or is this just a nice coincidence that turns out to be true?

See e.g. here. Does that help?

@TobiasFünke Maybe I have generalized too far, but for the theories that I have learned about so far (KG, Dirac, and YM) the propagator can be obtained by finding a Green's function. What are some theories where this does not hold? Also since you say that this is not true in general then I assume the 2-point function being Green's functions is a coincidence, is that right?

@TobiasFünke Sorry I'll try to make my question more clear. If we want to find the propagator to a free theory whose equation of motion are given by the operator $L$, the common approach is to "invert the operator", i.e. find a Greens function $G$ such that $LG = \delta$. Other than direct computation, why is finding a propagator the same as inverting the operator $L$? If this is still unclear please let me know.

@TobiasFünke Yes I took a look at that post, and I hope this is not a stupid question, but what does the 2-point function have to do with Hamiltonians?

Can you define the two-point function? You are, presumably, working in the Heisenberg picture, no?...

@TobiasFünke I am working with the 2-point function being defined as $\langle 0 | \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) | 0 \rangle$.

related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252213/84967

@AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you, this seems to be very close to what I'm looking for. So the fact that 2-point functions are always Green's functions follows from Eq. 3 in that post?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201482/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359961/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367763/2451 and links therein.

Your question is unclear. What exactly do you mean by $\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle$? Is it the vacuum expectation value of the time-ordered product of the two field operators, being indeed a Green function in the mathematical sense and the object usually referred to as the two-point Green function in QFT.  Or is it the Wightman function $\langle 0|\phi(x_1) \phi(x_2)|0\rangle$ as you did in one of your comments to a previous comment by @TobiasFünke? In the latter case, this object would not be a Green function (in the mathematical sense) but satisfies the homogeneous KG equation.

ctd. Are you talking about the two-point function of a free field theory or about the one of an interacting theory. In the latter case, are you familiar with the Källen-Lehmann representation?

@Hyperon Sorry I should have been more specific. I mean the time-ordered product of two field operators and I am referring to the two-point function of a free theory. I am familiar with the Källen-Lehmann representation.

@TobiasFünke I think the problem was on my end and me not fully understanding the answer in that link. Thank you very much for your help however!

It follows from the Schwinger-Dyson equations. Let's prove it for the case you're interested in (though the equations are more general). I will do it for a scalar field and let you work out the generalisations to Dirac spinors and gauge fields.
Let $S[\phi]$ be the action for some theory and consider a one-point function. By definition
$$
\langle \phi(x) \rangle = \int [d\phi] e^{i S[\phi]} \phi(x) = \int [d\phi] e^{i S[\phi+ \epsilon]} ( \phi(x) + \epsilon(x))
$$
In the second equality, we have shifted the integration variable $\phi(x) \to \phi(x) + \epsilon(x)$. Expanding RHS to first order in $\epsilon$, we find
\begin{align}
\langle \phi(x) \rangle &= \int [d\phi] e^{i S[\phi]} \left( 1 +  i \int d^d y E(\phi(y)) \epsilon(y) \right) ( \phi(x) + \epsilon(x) ) \\
&= \int [d\phi] e^{i S[\phi]} \left( \phi(x)  + \epsilon(x) +  i \int d^d y \phi(x) E(\phi(y)) \epsilon(y) \right) 
\end{align}
where $E(\phi(x))$ is the Euler-Lagrange equation for the action $S[\phi]$. The $O(1)$ term cancels on both sides. The $O(\epsilon)$ gives the equation
$$
\int d^d z \langle E(\phi(z))  \phi(y) \rangle \epsilon(z) = i \epsilon(y) 
$$
This is true for any $\epsilon$, so we can set $\epsilon(z) = \delta^d(z-x)$ and we find
$$
\langle E(\phi(x))  \phi(y) \rangle = i \delta^d(x-y).
$$
This is true in ALL theories for any action. Now consider a Gaussian theory with action $S[\phi] = - \frac{1}{2} \int d^d x [ ( \partial \phi )^2 + m^2 \phi^2 ] $ for which $E(\phi(x)) = ( \Box - m^2 ) \phi(x)$. In this case,
$$
( \Box - m^2 ) \langle \phi(x)  \phi(y) \rangle = i \delta^d(x-y). 
$$
But this is precisely what defines a Green's function (up to a factor of $i$. Therefore,
$$
\langle \phi(x)  \phi(y) \rangle = i G(x-y)
$$

Thank you very much, this clarifies everything I was unsure about!

You can generalize this to n-point functions and get the Schwinger-Dyson equation.
